# Alternatives to dynamically creating model fields

Tags: django, postgresql, data-structures

I'm trying to build a web application where users can upload a file (specifically the [MDF](https://www.asam.net/standards/detail/mdf/) file format) and view the data in forms of various charts. The files can contain any number of time based signals (various numeric data types) and users may name the signals wildly.

My thought on saving the data involves 2 steps:

1. Maintain a ***master table*** as an index, to save such meta information as file names, who uploaded it, when, etc. Records (rows) are added each time a new file is uploaded.
2. Create a new table (I'll refer to this as ***data tables***) for each file uploaded, within the table each column will be one signal (first column being timestamps).

This brings the problem that I can't pre-define the `Model` for the data tables because the number, name, and datatype of the fields will differ among virtually all uploaded files.

I'm aware of some libs that help to build runtime dynamic models but they're all dated and questions about them on SO basically get zero answers. So despite the effort to make it work, I'm not even sure my approach is the optimal way to do what I want to do.

I also came across [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-arrayfield) Postgres specifc model field which can take nested arrays (which I believe fits the 2-D time based signals lists). In theory I could parse the raw uploaded file and construct such an array and basically save all the data in one field. Not knowing the limit of size of data, this could also be a nightmare for the queries later on, since to create the charts it usually takes only a few columns of signals at a time, compared to a total of up to hundreds of signals.

So my question is:

Is there a better way to organize the storage of data? And how?

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the name, number and datatypes of the fields will differ for each user, then you do not need an ORM. What you need is a query builder or SQL string composition like [Psycopg](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/index.html). You will be programatically creating a table for each combination of user and uploaded file (if they are different) and programtically inserting the records.

Using postgresql might be a good choice, you might also create a GIN index on the arrays to speed up queries.

However, if you are primarily working with time-series data, then using a [time-series database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series_database) like InfluxDB, Prometheus makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks for the hints! Just to clarify as I'm a web app noob - are you suggesting not to use django at all or only skip the ORM part of it? Maybe I can take use of the forms for handling upload of files and serve the master table?

Comment: Skip the ORM part of it. ORMs are used when your model is consistent and only your records/rows will change. For ex - in a blog, you will have a post, tags and an author model. Properties of each model are same, just the values change. In your case, there is no such underlying common abstraction. New table for each file does not lend itself to an ORM so easily.